# Combine two textures in OBJ into single texture

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

I have an OBJ file that has two meshes mapped to two different texture files.  After cropping the meshes in Blender, I realized that most of the original image portions in the texture jpegs are not being used.

Hence I want to combine two textures into a single texture and export the meshes into a OBJ file.  How can I do this in Blender?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I had a deadline and used multiple textures for it. Thanks @raym for pointing out a related Q.  I tried TARDIS's answer to that question, but am getting a "Circular reference in Texture Stack" error and the complete model turns black.
Surely I'm missing something.  Do those techniques work for OBJ models that I've imported into blender?

Comment: Posted solutions on the other Q did not work for me, though this worked perfectly: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-S5QAac3U